# slow performance of data.table multi-column non-equi join with aggregates

Tags: r, join, data.table, multiple-columns

I'm trying to track down a performance problem and have largely isolated it to multi-column non-equi joins. below is a reasonable (but not exact) example of what I'm trying to do, along with timings.

```
library(quantmod)
library(data.table)

p <- last(OHLC(getSymbols("SPY", auto.assign = F,)), 700)
d <- as.data.table(p) #convert to a data.table for processing
d[, index := as.POSIXct(index)] #to match my use case. leaving as Date does not significantly alter timings
setnames(d, c("index", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close"))

# create partitions for analysis
partitions = unique(d[d, .(Top = x.Close, Bot = i.Close, Start = pmin(x.index, i.index)),
    on = .(Close >= Close), allow.cartesian = T][!is.na(Start)])

#desired analysis
system.time(r1 <- d[partitions, .(i.Top, i.Bot, i.Start, mean(x.Close), sd(x.Close)),
    on = .(Close >= Bot, Close <= Top, index >= Start), allow.cartesian = T, by = .EACHI])
#7.67
```

single column joins with the same data set are significantly faster (but don't produce needed results). just here for timing comparison:

```
system.time(r2 <- d[partitions, .(i.Top, i.Bot, i.Start, mean(x.Close), sd(x.Close)),
    on = .(Close >= Bot, Close <= Top), allow.cartesian = T, by = .EACHI])
#4.4
system.time(r4 <- d[partitions, .(i.Top, i.Bot, i.Start, mean(x.Close), sd(x.Close)),
    on = .(index >= Start), allow.cartesian = T, by = .EACHI])
#4.67
```

I understand that if I reduce the number of rows in the `partition` table, I can speed things up, but I've gone as far down that path as I can and its still slow. I also understand this requires a very large join to be materialized under the hood, but that materialized join is even bigger with just the single column constraints, so the relative performance is still troubling me.

Am I doing something wrong? I don't really understand why adding the the second column condition would result in such a dramatic slowdown. Any suggestions as to how to make this faster?

**EDIT 7/30/18**

so, after playing around with the very useful `verbose=T`, I have identified another aspect to my problem. It seems that `median()` is extremely slow in this context:

First, existing analysis using `mean()` with verbose output:

```
r1 <- d[partitions, .(i.Top, i.Bot, i.Start, mean(x.Close), sd(x.Close)),
    on = .(Close >= Bot, Close <= Top, index >= Start), allow.cartesian = T, by = .EACHI, verbose = T]

Non-equi join operators detected ... 
  forder took ... 0.000sec 
  Generating non-equi group ids ... done in 0.000sec 
  Recomputing forder with non-equi ids ... done in 0.000sec 
  Found 26 non-equi group(s) ...
Starting bmerge ...done in 0.790sec 
Detected that j uses these columns: i.Top,i.Bot,i.Start,x.Close 
lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'list(i.Top, i.Bot, i.Start, mean(x.Close), sd(x.Close))'
Old mean optimization changed j from 'list(i.Top, i.Bot, i.Start, mean(x.Close), sd(x.Close))' to 'list(i.Top, i.Bot, i.Start, .External(Cfastmean, x.Close, FALSE), sd(x.Close))'
Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ... 
  collecting discontiguous groups took 0.077s for 235273 groups
  eval(j) took 4.475s for 235273 calls
4.690sec
```

Next, similar analysis using median(), again with verbose output:

```
r1 <- d[partitions, .(i.Top, i.Bot, i.Start, median(x.Close), sd(x.Close)),
    on = .(Close >= Bot, Close <= Top, index >= Start), allow.cartesian = T, by = .EACHI, verbose = T]
Non-equi join operators detected ... 
  forder took ... 0.000sec 
  Generating non-equi group ids ... done in 0.000sec 
  Recomputing forder with non-equi ids ... done in 0.000sec 
  Found 26 non-equi group(s) ...
Starting bmerge ...done in 0.810sec 
Detected that j uses these columns: i.Top,i.Bot,i.Start,x.Close 
lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'list(i.Top, i.Bot, i.Start, median(x.Close), sd(x.Close))'
Old mean optimization is on, left j unchanged.
Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ... 
  collecting discontiguous groups took 0.079s for 235273 groups
  eval(j) took 12.826s for 235273 calls
13.1sec
```

For reference:

```
> getOption("datatable.optimize")
[1] Inf
```

So, I guess the other question is: is there any way to speed up the `median()` call within the context of the `non-equi` join with by  `.EACHI`

Comment: Use `verbose=TRUE` in your call and see how many 'non-equi' join groups are there... The more the non-equi groups, the more time it'll take. And more the non-equi conditions, the more likely it is to have more non-equi groups.. I try to explain the algo a bit in my useR talk: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/useR-international-R-User-conference/useR2016/Efficient-in-memory-non-equi-joins-using-datatable More non-equi groups == more binary searches. This could be made faster by parallelising (which I'd like to work on if/when I get some time).

Comment: Thanks for the info @Arun: `Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ... 
  collecting discontiguous groups took 0.014s for 77062 groups
  eval(j) took 3.943s for 77062 calls
4.030sec`  Does this mean the search is fast, but the actual computation over so many groups is the slow part?

Comment: I think the core issue here is that `median` is much slower than `mean`, and that we are not able to overcome. In both cases GForce was not used, so `mean` was also slow, comparing to `gmean`. If we make `gmean` and `gmedian` to work during join then this will be definitely faster, but still `mean` will be much faster than `median`.